# Automatic setup of Android SDK in Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have just installed Eclipse Juno on Ubuntu Linux 10.04 and created a new work-space to use for Android.

Both the Eclipse and the workspace folder were new, so I assume that when I start Eclipse no information from other Eclipse installations or work-spaces that are on my system are used.

Then I have started Eclipse and followed the instructions from [this page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) to install the Android plug-in from the [ADT Plugin](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) repository. The installation went fine and after installing the plug-ins, Eclipse was automatically restarted.

After restarting Eclipse, a dialogue was shown, asking to indicate a folder where Eclipse could install one or more android-sdks. The default path was

```
my_home_directory/android-sdks
```

Since I wanted to take a break I pushed on `cancel` planning to do this installation later.

When I restarted Eclipse, the dialogue was not shown any more. I could download the sdk myself but I would prefer to use the Eclipse built-in automatic installation.

So I thought that maybe Eclipse has saved some information about the fact that automatic installation was cancelled and is not offering to do it any more. I have deleted the work-space folder and the Eclipse installation folder, created new empty ones, unpacked the Eclipse archive again, and performed the Android plug-in installation again. To my surprise, the android-sdk automatic installation dialogue **does not** show up any more.

Does any one know how to solve this problem? I.e. how to

- either start the automatic Android-sdk installation procedure manually,
- or completely uninstall Eclipse so that it does not have any memory of previous installations and it automatically shows the installation dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which installation folder you are talking about. I think it may be the one that android uses to refer to its executables (like adb / monkey-runner).

Have you tried setting the path in Window -> Preferences -> Android -> SDK Location -> Browse ?

One you have done that you should be able to install an Android runtime using Window -> Android SDK Manager

Comment: Yes I can do what you suggest and that's what I am doing now. So I have downloaded an sdk myself, unpacked it, and set the path as you say. Now the SDK manager is running and installing the rest of the files. But the first time I had started Eclipse, a dialogue had opened and proposed to download everything automatically. I have seen it only the very first time and now there is no way I can get it again.

Comment: The installation folder I am talking about is the folder that Eclipse (or an Eclipse plugin) needed to know in order to download and install the Android sdk. The dialogue asked me: where should I install the Android sdk?

Comment: ahh I see. You are better off setting it manually via the preferences. It might be a bug on the eclipse plugin. You can save time by using the manual solution instead of trying to get the dialog back. Good luck with the installation.